# Hide div when a class is added via JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, plugins

I am working with [fullPage.js](https://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/extensions/scrolloverflow-reset.html) where an `active class` is added to a `li` via JS.

What I would like to do is, when a `li` (`#menu li:last-child`) has active class, hide `#menu`. But, due to the `active class` was added via JS, the code doesn't work:

```
$(window).on("scroll",function() {
    if ($('li:last-child').hasClass("active")) {
        $("#menu").hide();
    }
})
```

This is my HTML:

```
<ul id="menu">
    <li data-menuanchor="slide1"><a href="#slide1"><span></span></a></li>
    <li data-menuanchor="slide2"><a href="#slide2"><span></span></a></li>
</ul>

<div id="fullpage">
    <div class="section" id="section0">
        <div class="intro">
            <h1>Slide 1</h1>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="section" id="section1">
        <div class="intro">
            <h1>Slide 2</h1>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: you are missing $("#menu").hide();

Comment: Still doesn't work...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try .on or .live(). because you added class added with js so you can put .hide() under live() or on() function.

Answer (score 0):

Change below line -

```
("#menu").hide();
```

to

```
$("#menu").hide();
```

Comment: Still doesn't work...